# internal server error when creating new field

Tags: craft3, field, error

whenever i try to save a new field I get an internal server error in the backend of craft 3.

This happens whenever i want to create or modify a field that has an input like date, plain text, reactor... a category field for example works just fine.

I already checked the permissions on the FTP folders as craft requires.

this is the stack trace:

this is the stack trace i get when trying to edit a field.

```
#0 /srv/www/vhosts/safesolution.ch/httpdocs/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php(1302): PDOStatement->execute()
#1 /srv/www/vhosts/safesolution.ch/httpdocs/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php(1102): yii\db\Command->internalExecute()
#2 /srv/www/vhosts/safesolution.ch/httpdocs/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Fields.php(1844): yii\db\Command->execute()
#3 /srv/www/vhosts/safesolution.ch/httpdocs/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Fields.php(1704): craft\services\Fields->_updateColumn()
#4 /srv/www/vhosts/safesolution.ch/httpdocs/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Fields.php(895): craft\services\Fields->applyFieldSave()
#5 /srv/www/vhosts/safesolution.ch/httpdocs/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/base/ApplicationTrait.php(1664): craft\services\Fields->handleChangedField()
#6 /srv/www/vhosts/safesolution.ch/httpdocs/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/ProjectConfig.php(1189): craft\web\Application->craft\base\{closure}()
#7 [internal function]: craft\services\ProjectConfig->handleChangeEvent()
#8 /srv/www/vhosts/safesolution.ch/httpdocs/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php(628): call_user_func()
#9 /srv/www/vhosts/safesolution.ch/httpdocs/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/ProjectConfig.php(752): yii\base\Component->trigger()
#10 /srv/www/vhosts/safesolution.ch/httpdocs/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/ProjectConfig.php(521): craft\services\ProjectConfig->_processConfigChangesInternal()
#11 /srv/www/vhosts/safesolution.ch/httpdocs/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Fields.php(832): craft\services\ProjectConfig->set()
#12 /srv/www/vhosts/safesolution.ch/httpdocs/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/FieldsController.php(328): craft\services\Fields->saveField()
#13 [internal function]: craft\controllers\FieldsController->actionSaveField()
#14 /srv/www/vhosts/safesolution.ch/httpdocs/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array()
#15 /srv/www/vhosts/safesolution.ch/httpdocs/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(181): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams()
#16 /srv/www/vhosts/safesolution.ch/httpdocs/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(534): yii\base\Controller->runAction()
#17 /srv/www/vhosts/safesolution.ch/httpdocs/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(287): yii\base\Module->runAction()
#18 /srv/www/vhosts/safesolution.ch/httpdocs/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(596): craft\web\Application->runAction()
#19 /srv/www/vhosts/safesolution.ch/httpdocs/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(266): craft\web\Application->_processActionRequest()
#20 /srv/www/vhosts/safesolution.ch/httpdocs/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(392): craft\web\Application->handleRequest()
#21 /srv/www/vhosts/safesolution.ch/httpdocs/web/index.php(21): yii\base\Application->run()
#22 {main}
```

Has anyone experienced anything similar? Where should i search for the problem ?

Comment: What's the error and stack trace? If it's Craft-generated, it'll be in the Craft `storage/logs` folder and if it's web-server generated, it'll be in your web server's error logs.

Comment: just posted the stack trace from the craft logs

Comment: @user12636 The stack trace isn't very informative, what error message are you getting? If the server is only displaying 'Internal server error', try putting the site in development mode (where full exception views are displayed) and saving the field again to see the specific error message. Or find the exception message in the log.